# Using ChannelFactory with WorkflowServiceHost

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Is there a way to do the service inference on a workflow definition XAML to create an interface that can be distributed to the client to be used with ChannelFactory instead of the host exposing WSDL and the client having to generate a service definition by adding a service reference?

Comment: Does your question means "how can I call my wcf service, using ChannelFactory, without generating proxy from wsdl"?

Comment: Yes, evgenyl. I'd like to distribute an interface for my service, like in a "common" assembly and not rely on WSDL / mex endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in a three step process:

1. Temporarily exposing the metadata from the workflow service
2. Creating proxy code with svcutil
3. Changing configuration back to not exposing metadata

**In detail:**

- Include your XAMLX file which defines the service in a project that was created as "WCF Workflow Service Application" (DeclarativeServiceLibrary1)
- Compile the project
- Set the project as startup project
- Select xamlx file in Solution Explorer
- Press Ctrl-F5 -> WCF Test Client starts, you see your service loaded
- RightClick on the xamlx URL in WCF Test Client, choose Copy address (e.g. `http://localhost:56326/Service1.xamlx`)
- Open a VS2010 Admin console window
- Create the proxy code with **svcutil.exe**:

  - `cd /D %TEMP%`
  - `svcutil http://localhost:56326/Service1.xamlx`
  - This creates two files, a *.cs and a *.config, that contain the proxy code

I had a lot of problems with other ways of craeting the proxy code (inside VS2010), the external svcutil was the most stable way to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Achim, great documentation! Using svcutil was my plan B but I was holding out for something that might be a little easier. It's unfortunate that Visual Studio can parse the XAML to make a glitzy drag and drop and designer surface but can't output a simple interface code file especially since WorkflowServiceHost already does it on the fly.

Comment: Yes, things like that can really drive you mad, you are perfectly right. At least they gave us svcutil... :)